# WP action/filter to modify title before header output and article output?

Tags: filters, hooks, title, get-the-title

I'm trying to split test two versions of a posts title using a custom plugin. So far I haven't found the right filter or action to hook into to modify the title on the meta tag level before the page is output.

What I have found is the filter the_title but that looks to do it in the post content only, and not he document head.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title

Is this the right filter to use, and I just have to modify my theme template to accomplish the selected action? Can I do this strictly from a plugin without theme modification?

What I want to do is check if a GET variable is set, such as `?title_ver=1` and if it is set, then grab the appropriate post meta value for the alternative title.

Non working code

```
    function custom_modify_title( $title, $id = null ) {
        return 'CUSTOM '.$title;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_modify_title', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_modify_title', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter wp_title changes only the function *wp_title()* when it's called.

So, you must double check on your theme's source code if before your header is using wp_title.

Anyway, you can set your filter on *functions.php*. A function to identify your param GET should be something like so:

```
function maybe_change_wp_title_ver( $title, $sep ) {

    if ( isset( $_GET['title_ver'] ) && 1 === $_GET['title_ver'] ) {
        $title = 'My New Title';
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'maybe_change_wp_title_ver', 99, 2 ); //99 is set as priority (read comments)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll double check the theme. I have used that filter but it only modified the output on the content, not in the title tag. I'll report back.

Comment: it's using `wp_title('');` I'll see if I can hook in to that.

Comment: I'm using your code, but with wp_title as the hook, no luck yet. I'll see what the issue is.

Comment: If you paste my code on your functions.php, you should be able to see: **My New Title** instead of your titles when you refer _?title_ver=1_

Comment: I've updated my original post with my sample code. It's in a custom plugin I'm creating, and I'd like to use it here before modifying the theme. So that I can release this abroad and not worry about config issues.

Comment: Sorry, you can change the code refering the filter wp_title though, I'll update for you.

Comment: Could you try again? Now is refering the wp_title filter

Comment: We can change the priority and it might works. I believe another plugin is changing your title also.

Change from add_filter( 'wp_title', 'maybe_change_wp_title_ver', 10, 2 ); to add_filter( 'wp_title', 'maybe_change_wp_title_ver', 99, 2 );

Comment: No luck. Here is the title output in the theme `<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>` and I modified your code a bit just to see if the filter is working, but using this `return '~'.$title;` but it still didn't modify it. I don't think this is an issue you need to track down though, I think google may help me find out why my filter isn't working.

Comment: If the priority doesn't work, try deactivate some plugins which could make a filter also, like WP SEO or something like that. They might have another filter replacing our code. As bigger as your priority, last your filter will be called.